# fix tls in pe loader

Tags: windows, binary, portable-executable

When I can't load my pe to the base adress I should relocate absolute adress.
I relocate absolute adress in reloc section but sometimes I have some deference pointer with an absolute adress like that
`dword ptr ds:[4104B8h],0`
I think I should fix my tls but I don't understand how ?

thanks

Comment: You should rebuild rva's to force the entry point using scylla tools can save time on calculs, this should rebuild section part, fix api missing ... etc https://github.com/NtQuery/Scylla

Comment: That is neither TLS nor a pointer, simply a global variable in the data section.

Comment: But I really want to learn how it works so I prefer if I can do manually